# How do you flip a phone camera back and forth with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, android, video, video-streaming, getusermedia

I initialize the camera like this, but it only accesses the front facing "selfie" camera.

```
const initCamera = () => {
          navigator.mediaDevices
            .getUserMedia({
              video: true,
            })
            .then((stream) => {
              video.value.srcObject = stream;
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              hasCameraSupport.value = false;
            });
        };
```

My attempt at making the camera flip was to write a function for a click event that would toggle "user" (selfie cam) and "environment" (real cam), like this:

```
    let frontFace = true

    const turnCamera = () => {
      frontFace = !frontFace;
      navigator.mediaDevices
        .getUserMedia({
          video: true,
          facingMode: frontFace ? "user" : "environment",
        })
        .then((stream) => {
          video.value.srcObject = stream;
        });
    };
```

But that didn't work. I don't know why but I'm guessing because the camera was already initialized? Is that why?

Did I do something else wrong? This is the first time I've ever worked with cameras so I have no idea but I listened to this:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/front-and-rear-camera-access-with-javascripts-getusermedia

Can anybody here help? How do you flip the camera?

EDIT:

I also tried:

```
const switchCamera = () => {
  frontCamera.value = !frontCamera.value;
};

const initCamera = () => {
  navigator.mediaDevices
    .getUserMedia({
      video: true,
      facingMode: frontCamera ? "user" : "environment",
    })
    .then((stream) => {
      video.value.srcObject = stream;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      hasCameraSupport.value = false;
    });
};
```

but that doesnt work either